# Why do we use different cost functions in machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning

In most machine learning applications, we use Maximum Likelihood Estimation to derive appropriate cost functions. For example, if we assume that our model $f(x;\theta)$ yields the mean of a multivariate normal distribution (i.e. $p(y|x;\theta) = \mathcal{N}(y;f(x;\theta),I)$), we will obtain the mean squared error (MSE) $$ MSE(\theta) = \sum_{i=1}^M || y_i - f(x_i ;\theta)||^2. $$
Similarly, if we suppose that $f$ models the parameter of a bernoulli-distribution (i.e. $p(y|x;\theta) = \mathrm{Be}(y;f(x;\theta))$), we get the cross-entropy-loss (CEL): $$ CEL(\theta) = -\sum_{i=1}^M y_i \log f(x_i;\theta)+(1-y_i) \log(1-f(x_i;\theta)).$$
Assuming that the model is powerful enough, we obtain

- $f(x_i;\theta^*) = y_i$ for all $i=1,\dots,M$ iff
- $\theta^* = \arg\min_{\theta \in \Theta} MSE(\theta)$ iff
- $\theta^* = \arg\min_{\theta \in \Theta} CEL(\theta)$.

My question is: do we have any theoretical justifications on why we use different cost functions other than "it was derived using MLE"? For example, what exactly makes the CEL a better fit in certain scenarios than the MSE?

Edit: just to clarify a few points. If we make the assumption that our model is generally powerful enough (i.e. there is such a $\theta^*$ as described above), then why shouldn't we use the same cost function everywhere if the set of minimizers is the same?

Comment: I dont think there is a formal way to do it. Because this cost function is exactly our measure of "how good/wrong we are" and thus comparing the cost functions is rather hard. We dont know "whats better", since there is no definition for "better"

Comment: Do you have any specific examples you are curious about?  This is rather open-ended and it's not clear to me what other loss functions you might be thinking of.  "MLE" is a perfectly good justification for using a particular loss function; I'm not sure why you've rejected that justifications and looking for other justifications?  Perhaps you can edit the question to clarify these points?

Comment: Thanks for your questions. I tried to clarify the text.